# How to open a assetportalbrowser in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to use a assetportalbrowser in SharePoint 2010 to attach an existing document in another list?

What I tried so far:

```
function InitiateAssetPickerPopUp() {

  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.Web = context.get_web();
  context.load(this.Web);
  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess),
                            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {

  var options = {
    title: 'My Dialog',
    width: 500,
    height: 600,
    showClose: false,
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl
         + '/_layouts/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx?&AssetUrl='
         + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl
         + '&   RootFolder='
         + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl
         + '&MDWeb='
         + this.Web.get_id()
         + '&AssetType=Link',
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult) {
      alert(dialogResult);
    }
  };
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
  alert('Failed:' + args.get_message());
}
```

But it does not open the popup?!

Comment: Why your url to AssetPortalBrowser has spaces after layouts? "/_layouts    "

Comment: It was a mistake to pass the code to blog

Comment: are there any javascript errors?